# Subsonic - Migration from 2.2 to 3.0

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Where can I find an examples of code migration from SubsSonic 2.2 to 3.0.
For example we have Subssonic 2.2 code:

```
public static void SavePageModules(PageModuleCollection modCol)
{
            modCol.SaveAll();
}
```

How do we write this method for 3.0.
Are Collection deprecated in 3.0.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent for SaveAll in Subsonic 3.  I suggest you check the batch query feature: http://subsonicproject.com/docs/BatchQuery  The migration implies rewrite code, since Subsonic 3 has been constructed over a different schema and using another paltform: the framework 3.5.